# Sqoop from Postgre to Hive and convert to ORC format

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, sqoop, orc

I'm trying to sqoop some tables from Postgres to Hive and convert them to ORC while sqooping.

1. I used the below command.

> sqoop import --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --connect
> jdbc:postgresql:/// --username user --password pwd
> --table table --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table table  --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile" --create-hcatalog-table -m 1

I was getting the below error:

> ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed:
> org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2016 : Error operation
> not supported : Store into a transactional table default.agent from
> Pig/Mapreduce is not supported

2. I changed the sqoop to look like this, added tblproperties ("transactional"="false")

> sqoop import --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --connect
> jdbc:postgresql:/// --username user --password pwd
> --table table --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table table  --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile tblproperties ("transactional"="false")" --create-hcatalog-table -m 1

Error:

> INFO hcat.SqoopHCatUtilities: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1
> from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
> MetaException(message:Table default.duplicates failed strict managed
> table checks due to the following reason: Table is marked as a managed
> table but is not transactional.)

3. and I added the below after some googling, added --hcatalog-external-table in two different format

> sqoop import --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --connect
> jdbc:postgresql:/// --username user --password pwd
> --table table --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-table table  --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile tblproperties ("transactional"="false")" --create-hcatalog-table
> --hcatalog-external-table -m 1

and

> sqoop import --hcatalog-home /usr/hdp/current/hive-webhcat --connect
> jdbc:postgresql:/// --username user --password pwd
> --table table --hcatalog-database default --hcatalog-external-table table  --hcatalog-storage-stanza "stored as orcfile tblproperties
> ("transactional"="false")" --create-hcatalog-table -m 1

I tried both given above,

This is the Error:

> ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument:
> --hcatalog-external-table

Now, I'm stuck.. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might have better luck with Spark JDBC reader and ORC-format HDFS writer (or Hive writer)

Comment: @OneCricketeer any link you can give me, so I can follow up more on what you said?

Comment: The Spark documentation is all I would link you to

Answer (score 0):

it works！ may help you
Arguments         :
import
--connect
jdbc:postgresql://****:5432/cloudoffice_2
--username
dbmanager
--password-file
********
--table
hive_ua_test_with_column_5
--hcatalog-database
temp
--hcatalog-table
ua_test_adb
--split-by
id
-m
4
--hcatalog-storage-stanza
stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
--verbose
--where
created>=1661356800 and created<1661443200
--hive-partition-key
date
--hive-partition-value
2022-08-25
--columns
id,ip_address